# Undefined array key "name_of_firm" in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-ui

This is my RegisterController (Laravel ui edited). please help me.
Is i have to add any other page to this question.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'name_of_firm' => $data['name_of_firm'],
        'number' => $data['number'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
    ]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `dd($data)` before returning the created user to check if `name_of_firm` exists in the `$data` array.

Comment: check in your $data you are getting key "name_of_firm" or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 case if `name_of_firm` is nullable or required

## Case : 1

#### if `name_of_firm` is required

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'name_of_firm' => ['required']
    ]);
}


/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'name_of_firm' => $data['name_of_firm'],
        'number' => $data['number'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
    ]);
}
```

## Case : 2

#### if `name_of_firm` is nullable

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}


/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'name_of_firm' => $data['name_of_firm'] ?? null, // make sure database is accept null value
        'number' => $data['number'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: And what can we do in case we have a field that can be, for example, null or a foreign key ID? How can we add that kind of validation logic?

Comment: if field accept null you can use case 2

Comment: Not exactly the same since I would need "name_of_firm" to have some rules and the error would still be thrown. In case someone finds themselves with the same case, using the "sometimes" rule in addition to the "nullable" rule solves this and allows other rules when the field is not null and present in the request.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `data_get` or `Arr::get()` helpers to solved not exists element:

```php
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'name_of_firm' => data_get($data, 'name_of_firm'),
        'number' => data_get($data, 'number'),
        'address' => data_get($data, 'address')],
    ]);
}
```